# app engine deploy with [13] Error processing user code

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I download google official latest Node.js app engine demo and deploy to standard env, but this problem arises:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Error processing user code.
```

Here is the demo url:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/standard

Someone can take a look for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has happened before whenever the default App Engine service accounts gets deleted.

Please check that you have have it and it has been not modified.

In case you don't have it (it has been deleted), a workaround would be to use the [Undelete API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete) to restore the Default App Engine service account.

You will need to input your service account's unique numeric ID, which can be found in your console's [activity logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity).